# Angular http testing

Tags: testing, mocking, angularjs

I have a fairly simple controller that gets a simple json list of objects ...

```
function ProductGroupsCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams, sharedService, popupService) {

$scope.list = null;
$scope.selectedItem = null;
$scope.selectedItemJsonString = '';

$scope.selectItem = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
    $scope.selectedItemJsonString = JSON.stringify(item);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(item));
};

$scope.closePopup = function () {
    $scope.selectedItem = null;
    $scope.selectedItemJsonString = '';
};

// sharedService.prepForBroadcast($routeParams.anotherVar);

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/ProductGroup'
}).success(function (data) {
    $scope.list = data;
}).
error(function (data) {
    $scope.message = 'There was an error with the data request.';
});

}
```

I then try to mock the request in the test class:

```
var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend, sharedServiceMock = {}, popupServiceMock = {};

beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    $httsypBackend.expectGET('/ProductGroup').
    respond([{
        ProductGroupID: 5,
        MenuTitle: "Promotional Products",
        AlternativeText: "Coming soon - a collection of environmentally friendly Promotional Products",
        OrdinalPosition: 5,
        Active: false
    }]);


    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller(ProductGroupsCtrl, {
        $scope: scope,
        $http: $httpBackend,
        sharedService: sharedServiceMock,
        popupService: popupServiceMock
    });}));
```

However I receive an error in the testacular window `object undefined`. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Is the `$httsypBackend` in `$httsypBackend.expectGET('/ProductGroup').` a typo? If not, that would be your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. I copied and pasted into another editor so I could get the question accepted as I use 2 tab spaces usually. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. If I remove the error callback function from the $http.get method then it works, i.e. remove the following ...

```
error(function (data) {
    $scope.message = 'There was an error with the data request.';
}
```

I have to say Angular sure is a steep learning curve for someone who is not a day to day JavaScript programmer (although I seem to be doing  more and more). Thanks for the help anyway KatieK :-)